# What is the genome size of Saffron (Crocus sativus)?

Tags: botany, genomes

I searched the web but cannot find an answer for my question. Has the genome size of *Crocus sativus* been determined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither NCBI nor Ensembl have a genome project listed for any crocus species, although individual ethidium bromide stained nuclei have been analyzed by flow cytometry, [revealing approximately 11.4 pg of DNA per nucleus](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00985356) (warning, pay wall).

*C. sativus* is triploid, giving it a [C-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-value) of 3.8 pg which works out to a haploid genetic content of about 3.45 Gbp.

(full credit to [canadianer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/6307/canadianer) for finding the Brandizzi paper)

Comment: Here's a paper that actually measures C. sativus: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00985356 They got around 11.3 pg and 3.45 Gb

Comment: 3.45 Gb is apparently for the haploid genome, by the way.

Comment: Yep, you nailed this question. Why not put it as an actual answer instead of commenting on my, less awesome, answer? I feel like I should actually delete mine now.

Comment: Haha well when I first read it the numbers were so close that I thought it was just confirming your estimate. I can post an answer later if I get time, but feel free to edit yours.